# How to add profile image into user profile

Tags: users

I am using D6. I want that users are able to upload their profile image like gmail, Facebook. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got how to upload photo into your profile. First install core module "profile". Go to "user setting" and set the profile image path, if you will get an error like "The directory does not exists".

Follow this instructions---- "go to the database and find a table named 'variable'. In this table find out the entry user_picture_path and put a value like this - s:8:"pictures"; where '8' is the length of the path string - 'pictures' which should be in the directory specified in the file system configuration.
After setting the variable go in the user settings and change the path accordingly (in this case just write - pictures) and save it."

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6 the, goto solution for this is the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module which allows you to add CCK fields to your user profile (in Drupal 7, the fields API allows you to do this in core):

> This module builds user profiles as content (aka nodes), which opens
>   the opportunity to use all the powerful modules for content for user
>   profiles too, e.g. the Content Construction Kit (CCK). It's intended
>   to be simple and useful, but extensible by further modules.

You will also want to install the [imagefield module](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) to be able to add an image upload CCK field.

Comment: And don't forget [Image Cache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) to be able to resize / cut them to size for your users! Again, 7 has it in core.

Comment: I did and able to upload image into user profile. But how can it be shown into Blog posts?

Comment: I am working with wamp server. when i enable picture support unser user profile setting and put the path for images an error occur "The directory does not exist.". What to do?

Comment: All is working well. Now, i am able to upload images into user profile. How these pictures shown into blog posts pages. I am using pixture reloaded Theme. I have already ckecked the option "user pictures in post".???????????